# Rspec controller tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I wanted to keep my controller tests DRY, readable, and make writing new tests very simple so that it encourages good practices like one assertion per test (if you have to redo a lot of work over and over, chances are you're just gonna shove more assertions into the same test to avoid the extra work).

Here's the strategy I'm using:

```
RSpec.describe FireController do
    let(:do_request) { post :create, request_body }
    let(:request_body) { {} }

    describe '#create' do
       context 'when we have firewood' do
           let(:request_body) { { firewood: true } }
           it 'creates fire' do
               do_request
               expect(response.body).to eql('fire!!!')
           end
       end
    end
end
```

I would like some opinions on potential downsides to a strategy like this.

Comment: `do_request` seems like unnecessary indirection.  I'd rather read `post :create, request_body`.  Other than that this seems fine.  I'm unclear what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `let` is used to create data or functionality that is the same for each individual spec. In this example, I don't see much difference between your code and:

```
it 'creates fire' do
  params = { firewood: true }
  post :create, params
  expect(response.body).to eql('fire!!!')
end
```

If you need to pass `{ firewood: true }` to multiple specs, then using `let` to define the controller params makes sense. Furthermore, a `before_each` is more declarative for executing behavior. Use `let` to mock up data, but use `before_each` to execute the same behavior or methods for each spec:

```
RSpec.describe FireController do
  describe '#create' do
    context 'when we have firewood' do
      let :params, { { firewood: true } }

      before_each do
        post :create, params
      end

      it 'creates fire' do
        expect(response.body).to eql('fire!!!')
      end

      it 'is really really on fire' do
        expect(...).to ...
      end

      it 'does something else as well' do
        expect(...).to ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This way each spec is literally reduced to a single `expect`.

---

@jtmarmon said:

> the reason I didn't run the request in before_each is because some specs need to check if a method get called. those expectations need to be set before the request is made

In this case I would either:

1. Just call `post :create, params` in each spec, or
2. Group those specs inside additional `context`s that contain their own `before_each`s setting up the method call expectations

You aren't gaining clarity, or really reducing code by encapsulating `post :create, params` with a `let`. Every time I see a `let` I think it is setting up data, rather than executing behavior.

Comment: the reason I didn't run the request in before_each is because some specs need to check if a method get called. those expectations need to be set before the request is made

Comment: but yes, i'm sharing :params between specs so that's why I have it in a let

Comment: @jtmarmon: I've updated my answer based on your comments.